# How can i import script js in java android?

Tags: javascript, java, android

Today I have problem with javascript that execute in Java. I use library JsEvaluator to do this . Firstly I have one script to execute and I called it inside java code by JsEvaluator. Script is received . But It dose not execute script. I have code JsEvaluator below. My question is "Why my script is not execute by method mJsEvaluator.evaluate ?" . Thank you for your great idea.

```
JsEvaluator mJsEvaluator;
        private Scanner scanner;
        String jsCode;
    protected void testCryptoJs(String val) {
            jsCode += loadJs("real_library/rsa.js");
            jsCode += "; ";
    //      jsCode += "var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('CryptoJs is working!', 'Secret Passphrase');"
    //              + "var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'Secret Passphrase');"
    //              + "jsEvaluatorResult += ' ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); ";

            jsCode += "var decrypted = Base64.decode('"+val+"');" +
                    "jsEvaluatorResult = decrypted; ";

        }

        protected void evaluateAndDisplay() {
            mJsEvaluator.evaluate(jsCode, new JsCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final String resultValue) {
                    String s = resultValue;
                    final TextView jsResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.realLibraryResult);
                    jsResultTextView.setText(String.format("Result:%s", resultValue));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                    final TextView jsResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.realLibraryResult);
                    jsResultTextView.setText(JSUtils.getErrorSpan(errorMessage));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Brother i create my own decryption in javascription

Comment: i initialize in constructor  mJsEvaluator = new JsEvaluator(this);
  jsCode = "var jsEvaluatorResult = ''; ";

Comment: Wrap in in a self running function perhaps? (function () {//code});

Comment: brother @Simon Hyll  script is receive value, but it is not return value from function i defined.